# Regex: Replacing a string in a sub-string only

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

I have special file format where I need to replace dozens of strings and reformat its structure. As the simplest solution I have prepared my patterns file where all regex definitions/replacements are stored (~100 replacements). I'm using perl to find and replace patterns (`perl -p patterns source.file`). Everything so far so good.

However, there is one case I'm unable to resolve using regex. I need to replace strings in part of the whole line, i.e. replace string in within a sub-string only.

**Example:** For simplicity, I need to replace all "A" to "X" only in the middle string (delimited by ;).

Input line:

```
ABCD ABCD; ABCD ABCD; ABCD ABCD
```

Expected output:

```
ABCD ABCD; XBCD XBCD; ABCD ABCD
           ^    ^
           the only replaced characters
```

This correctly replaces all characters:

```
s/A/X/g;
```

But I need to replace commas in the middle field only. I tried:

```
s/(.*?;.*?)A/\1X/g;
s/(.*?;.*)A(.*?;)/\1X\2/g;  # alternative to find the last A
```

But this replaces either the first A. I can have multiple patterns like this to repeat the search&replace procedure but this does not sound like a good solution as I don't know how many A's I will have in the sub-string.

I tried to play with lookbehind but unsuccessfully. Please note, I just need a regex definition I could use in my patterns file (i.e. no perl code). Alternatively, I'm able to use `sed` or `awk` to handle this case but I'm not too much familiar with it.

Thanks, community!

Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/Ic4ciA/1

Comment: Are you restricted to `sed` and `awk`, or is there a programming language which you can use here?

Comment: This replacing procedure is just one of the actions in my `bash` script so I can just any simple command to the pipeline. I think I would be able to handle this using some code (I'm pretty familiar with `python`). But I'm more curious if it's possible to match&replace the strings with some special regex pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A perl one liner:

```
echo 'ABCD ABCD; ABCD ABCD; ABCD ABCD' | perl -pe 's/(?:.+?;|\G).*?\KA(?=.*?;)/X/g'
ABCD ABCD; XBCD XBCD; ABCD ABCD
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?:             # non capture group
    .+?         # 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
    ;           # semicolon
  |             # OR
    \G          # restart from last match position
)               # end group
.*?             # 0 or more any character but newline, not greedy
\K              # forget all we have seen until  this position
A               # letter A
(?=             # positive lookahead, make sure we have after:
    .*?         # 0 or more any character but newline, not greedy
    ;           # a semicolon
)               # end lookahead
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ic4ciA/2)

Comment: Wow, this is awesome! Very functional and on top of that I've learned many new things - non-capturing groups, `\G` and `\K`. Many thanks, Toto!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a clean way to do this in one go using a regex tool alone.  But if you are open to a more iterative approach, it can fairly easily be handled in any scripting language.  Here is a Python script which gets the job done:

```
inp = "ABCD ABCD; ABCD ABCD; ABCD ABCD"
parts = inp.split(';')

index = 1
while index < len(parts)-1:
    parts[index] = parts[index].replace('A', 'X')
    index += 1

output = ';'.join(parts)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
ABCD ABCD; XBCD XBCD; ABCD ABCD
```

The approach is to split the input string on semicolon, generating a list of terms.  Then, iterate from the second to second-to-last term, doing a replacement of the letter `A` to `X`.  Finally, join together to produce the output you want.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly my "backup" solution, i.e. breakdown the line, replace required strings in its sub-string and then concatenate the parts back. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: I like your backup solution more than any alternative.  The thing is, you don't even need regex here for the replacement, and regex alone isn't a parsing/iterating tool.  Even using from a programming language, you will still need to iterate to get the behavior you want.